# After Form submission displaying error

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, redhat

After submitting the form to the server, i am getting following error.

[image]

Following are the site details,

1. Language: PHP
2. CMS: WordPress
3. Server: Apache
4. OS: Linux(redhat)

I have done a lot of search by googling. It was mentioned that, which are **X-Frame-options**, http reponse headers used in stopping for click-jacking attacks. I hope, which are not responsible for the issue, there is something else, i am unable to figure out. please, suggest me.

Comment: How do you post it? What is the exact answer? What is the handler? Which browser? Have you tried other browsers? It seems like the raw HTTP response is displayed instead of the content. That `0 ` at the beginning (before HTTP/1.1) is very odd though.

Comment: That Screenshot was sent by my client. Chrome browser(updated). But wired thing here is, for only one customer, this issue was reported. No another customer reported & no issue is there, with remaining ones. Even i also tested in few systems, working fine. Issue is with only one customer, i checked customer browser, extensions and version was also updated one.